# Send relational data using Json to wcf services

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

Roles and Privileges have relationship 1 to many. but while retrieving roles i am getting null value "[]" for the privileges. I am using Json to send data to wcf services using EF6 having code first approach.

code :

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer objJSSerializer = 
     new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string strJSON1 = objJSSerializer.Serialize((
        from role in  context.Roles select role)
       .ToList());
```

output:

> [{"privileges":[],"users":[],"ID":1,"RoleName":"Admin","IsActive":1},
>
> {"privileges":[],"users":[],"ID":2,"RoleName":"Apprisal Minister","IsActive":0}]

I tried `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` but still not able to get the privileges.

Basically, The problem, I am getting is that when i try to serialize the roles object. It doesn't serialize the relational data. I mean privileges are not there.

Which is the right way to get relational data in entity framework6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you mean load the Roles and it's related Privileges but this should work

```
var roles = dbContext().Roles.Include(r => r.Privileges);
```

And to serialize it use Newtonsoft.Json ( nugget package ) it handels relations but not circular refs. so if  any references in Privileges to Roles , use attribute `[JsonIgnore]` on the properties

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles);
```

Comment: Hi Thorarins, Thanks for your reply. Basically, The problem, I am getting is that when i try to serialize the roles object. It doesn't serialize the relational data. I mean privileges are not there.

Comment: ok , that's another one , do you have the data before serializing?

Comment: change the serialization code and use Newtonsoft serializer instead it handles relations and is much better then the one in the framework , see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks Thorarins, I am able to getting the values as u said.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework has lazy loading enabled by default which means that related items are not automatically retrieved from the database.

Let's imagine you have a blog containing multiple blog posts, each blog post has an author and many comments

```
1 Post has 1 Author
1 Post has many Comments 
1 Comment has 1 Author
1 Author has many posts
1 Author has many comments
```

Now to retrieve a blog posts with the related author of the post, the comments and the authors of the comments, you need to use the `Include()` extension method on your `DbSet<TEntity>` with the name of the related type added as a parameter..

```
using(var context = new BlogContext)
{
     var blogsDetailed = context.Blogs.Include("Author")
                           .Include("Comments.Author);
 }
```

There may be syntax errors as I'm typing from iPhone but that's the idea behind it